# Setting default option in Python of two mutually exclusive options using the argparse module

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="List or update! That is the question!")

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-l', '--list', dest="update", action='store_false')
group.add_argument('-u', '--update', dest="update", action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

If the user does not specify any optional arguments I want `update=False`.

[Edit]: I changed my question to not be so general, it was confusing. Sorry.

Comment: You write about what the current behavior is but not about what you're looking for.  Do  you like the current behavior but find the syntax too verbose?  Do you want slightly different behavior?

Comment: I´be tried to be less general. I think it´s possible to tell what I am looking for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should set different `dest` for the 2 options.

```
group.add_argument('-f', '--foo', dest="foo", action='store_false')
```

Comment: I´be tried to be less general. I think it´s possible to tell what I am looking for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want `add_mutually_exclusive_group()`. The documentation is [here](http://argparse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/other-methods.html#mutual-exclusion).

Comment: I´be tried to be less general. I think it´s possible to tell what I am looking for now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `default=False` for the `--list` option's parameters makes it do what you want.  I am not exactly sure why, and note that adding it to the `--update` option's parameters instead does nothing.