# How to set default value for mutually exclusive variable, but disable it when the argument is not supplied?

Tags: python, argparse, default-value

I'm new to argparse and don't know how to set default value of a mutual variable. In particular:

I have two variables and only one of them should be set. For example:

```
import argparse

PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser()

GROUP = PARSER.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

GROUP.add_argument(
        '--a',
        type=int,
        nargs='?',
        const=1,
        default=1)

GROUP.add_argument(
        '--b',
        type=int)

PARSER.set_defaults(train_pass=1)
```

The expected behaviors are:

1. At most one of a and b can be set.
2. If neither a and b are set, a should be default to 1, and b should be None.
3. If either a or b are set, the other value should be None.

However, even if I supply task.py --b 10, it will still set a's value to 1.

I checked this answer: [Set the default to false if another mutually exclusive argument is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303547/set-the-default-to-false-if-another-mutually-exclusive-argument-is-true), but it does different things. It wants the value to be the default value (i.e., 1 here) rather than None when b is set.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Defaults don't change just because an argument is in a mutually exclusive group.  All the group does is keep you trom using both arguments at once.  That is '--a 2 --b 4` should raise an error, that is all.  Otherwise '--a' and '--b' get defaults or values as their definition specifies.

Comment: `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` can be used to keep an attribute out of the namespace if it isn't provided.  But keep in mind that the default default `None` is a reliable indicator for an argument that was not used.  The user can't set that value.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? The problem is that I do want a to be set to 1, if both a and b are not explicitly set. But if b is set, I want the default not kicking in, i.e., a should be None.

Comment: Any interaction between `b` and `a` values, default or otherwise, is best done after parsing.